# package 'preprocess' installing error using pip command

Tags: python, pip, package

I am trying to install the package 'preprocess' from inside terminal of pyCharm IDE but it is showing the folloiwing error.

i tried this command

```
pip install preprocess
```

and I am getting following errors

```
Collecting preprocess
Using cached 
    https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/f9/559841df6c91428a2024ce120d92        192844178e4b2ceec1da84ce18205380/pr
    eprocess-1.1.0.zip
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\majid\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-        32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sy
    s.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\majid\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-        install-rsxg10hs\\preprocess\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\
    Users\\majid\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-        rsxg10hs\\preprocess\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"',         open
    )(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',         '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg
    _info --egg-base 'C:\Users\majid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-        rsxg10hs\preprocess\pip-egg-info'

cwd: C:\Users\majid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-        rsxg10hs\preprocess\
    Complete output (8 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\majid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rsxg10hs\preprocess\setup.py", line 28, in <module>
    import preprocess
  File "C:\Users\majid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rsxg10hs\preprocess\lib\preprocess.py", line 264
    except Exception, ex:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py         egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [release history of the project `preprocess`](https://pypi.org/project/preprocess/#history) shows, it's a very old project that hasn't had a release in over 10 years. It is very unlikely to be compatible with current versions of Python. The error output in the question seems to show the error message comes from trying to install the project for Python 3.8 and the error itself seems to show that it fails on code with the Python 2 syntax.

I would not recommend using this project at all. Alternatively you could try using it with a Python 2 version of the interpreter.